# How to access the same site cookie when in iframe

Tags: session, cookies, iframe, samesite

There are site A which is mine, and site B which I have no control of.
Site B redirects to saml authorization on my site A (step 1), then my site A redirects back to site B.
After that there is page of my site A embeded in iframe on site B (step 2).

Is there any modern way to pass information between my site A on a top level (step 1) and my site A in iframe (step 2)? I did it years ago by using Same-Site=None cookie, but now Firefox block this solution by default and Chrome will stop supporting it by 2025. Both sites are mine, so why couldn't I let them pass data, even if they are iframed?

New chrome proposal - partioned cookies (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/chips/) do not work at all in my case.
First party sets also don't help as I need to access the data server-side, not in javascript (for example for rendering emeded jpg image on site B). Using local storage seems to work on Chrome now, but it's blocked on Firefox.

Comment: Can you share a link about Chrome's plans to stop supporting `SameSite=None`?